Integrating PAN OCR - How to form Mulitpart/form-code data of image in APEX class? Uploading image from LWC.?
Integrating PAN OCR - How to form Mulitpart/form-code data of image in APEX class? Uploading image from LWC.

This question is similar to: How can I compose a multipart/form-data request?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
